# Is it possible to call putExtras() and getExtra() without starting a new activity?

Tags: android

I'm having two activities which are displayed side by side on one screen through a fragment for each activity. I want to send a String when I click a button on one of the activity, and then the other activity should retrieve the String I sent.

I know that it's possible to do that with the classic way `setString()` and `getString()` methods. But I'm wondering, could it be accomplished with `putExtra()` and `getExtra()` without opening the targeted activity on a new screen?

Comment: can you see my further question below? thx

Answer (score 0):

You can have both activity's **`intent`** as **global variable** and try using `putExtra()` from one activity and then `getExtra()` by another activity.

For Example,

```
public class activityOne extends Activity
{
   public static Intent intent = null;
   @Override
   protected synchronized final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      intent = getIntent();
   }
}

public class activityTwo extends Activity
{
   public static Intent intent = null;
   @Override
   protected synchronized final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      intent = getIntent();
   }
}
```

Now wherever you want you can access their intent like `activityOne.intent,activityTwo.intent` followed by **null** check

Comment: I call this on one method Intent listIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
  listIntent.putExtra("text", vidLocation.text); and retrieve it like this on the other method Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  text = extras.getString("text"); but it doesnt work

Comment: Your Receiving part should be inside your DetailsActivity class.

Comment: what do you mean by both activity's intent as global variable? Can you gimme an example? thx

Comment: the thing is when I call startActivity(intent); it opens the activity on a new screen. I dont want to open the targeted activity on a new screen, since the activity is displayed on the screen already together  with the activity where I send the Extra. (I'm using fragments in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the intent as a broadcast and have the receiving fragment register to that broadcast on its start (and unregister on its destroy).

Sending fragment:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(PARAM_TRANSFER);
intent.putExtra(key, extra);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Receiving fragment:

register:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(PARAM_TRANSFER);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

unregister:

```
try {
   unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

getting the param:

```
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     intent.getExtra(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the function of register and unregister?

Comment: the fragment that should receive the intent registers/unregisters as a listener for that broadcast, read up on BroadcastReceivers I think that's exactly what you need